# Right div on float:right appears a line below the left one

Tags: css, html, css-float

Here's my problem.

I have a wrapper div(width: 800px and height: 250px) which contains two divs occupying all the space in height and dividing their width in half.

I set up my css, float the right div to float: right and this one appears where it should but "below" the other one, exceeding the wrapper div space(which shouldn't even be possibile).

I'm posting both the jdfiddle and the code.

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- left div -->
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- right div -->
    <div id="rightDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px; }

#leftDiv {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px; }

#rightDiv {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just shift the div with ID `rightDiv` above the div with ID `leftDiv`. That's it.

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/2/)**

**The Code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- right div -->
    <div id="rightDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>    
    <!-- left div -->
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If that's the solution shouldn't I put float:left instead of float:right on the rightDiv or float the other one?

Having the right div before the left one is illogical considering occidental reading.

Thank you of course for the working solution, i'm just curious if there's a more logical way to write this down.

Comment: If you put a 'float:left' to your `leftDiv`, it will convey `float:left` for `leftDiv` and `float:right` for `rightDiv`. But if you have to put some elements and you do not want to change the css, going with the way I have mentioned is perfectly fine. As `rightDiv` has a `float:right` and `leftDiv` is just a `div` with regular characteristics.

Comment: I'm actually able to change the CSS as much as i want. I'm working on a single-page, clean and minimalistic layout and this section is totally fresh and not connected with the other ones so there's no problem changing the CSS structure!

Comment: Then I suggest you to add `float:left` for leftDiv as well as the rightDiv. Here is the working solution for the same. http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/7/ - @daghene

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/1/

You should add `float: left` to your left div.

Comment: I thought that when you have two elements you just float one and that's enough, am i mistaken?

Also why is the green div exceeding the height while there's no more content to display? I know an overflow:hidden solves the problem but i actually thought it was way easier and that i needed a single "float".

Comment: If you want floated child elements to extend the wrapping div (height), you should use the 'clearfix' method (see Rohit Azad's answer).
A single float would be useful if the other elements in the div were inline elements. In you case, there are two block-level elements. Thus you should float them both.

Answer (score 0):

Add float: left to the other div. Also you can use float: left for both; unless you have other reasons than just positioning there to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this code**

```
        #leftDiv{float:left;}
        #wrapper:after{
            content:"";
            clear:both;
            display:table;

        }
    #wrapper {
height:200px; // remove this line
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/5/

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;

}

#leftDiv {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
      float:left;

}

#rightDiv {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px; }
```

Comment: i can;t copy this answer ok @ Natheen Lee

Comment: I know you may have not copied, but it is already answered. And it is Nathan not Natheen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float your div to the right — you just need to align each block beside the other, and you can do this using `float: left;`.

I made a consistent solution for you. See below:

Using a class to remove the **DRY** of your code, I grouped your blocks into a common class with common behaviors.

See your new CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px; }

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

#leftDiv {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 200px; }

#rightDiv {
    background-color: green;
    height: 250px; }
```

And your new HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- left div -->
    <div class="block" id="leftDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- right div -->
    <div class="block" id="rightDiv">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using classes to execute common behaviors it is a good practice to avoid redundancy and future problems.

To see your code working on jsFiddle, [just click here](http://jsfiddle.net/FV9yC/6/).